$A \leq B, A\leq r^{-\alpha}B \implies A\leq C(1+r)^{-\alpha}B$
Let $A>0, B>0, r>0.$ Assume that $A \leq B$ and $A\leq r^{-\alpha}B$ for $\alpha>0.$
Question:Can we say that $A\leq C(1+r)^{-\alpha}B$ for $C$ some constant.
Edit: $C$ must be independent of $r$

What does constant mean here? What are the variables? Why can't you take $C=A(1+r)^{\alpha}$

@geetha290krm: Thanks. I've edited question. $C$ must be independent of $r$

I actually got a $C$ independent of $A,B$ and $r$!.

What you want is $\min\{r^{-\alpha}B, B\} \le C (1+r)^{-\alpha }B$ or $\min\{r^{-\alpha}, 1\} \le C (1+r)^{-\alpha }$. Or $\min\{(1+r)^{\alpha },(1+\frac 1 r)^{\alpha } \}\le C$. This is true with $C=2^{\alpha}$. [To see this just consider the cases $r\le 1$ and $r>1$].
